# how to get input as character from keyboard to uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, uikeyboard

I am doing a customized keyboard, but I don't know how to show it in uitextfield. How can I do this ? (I use UIView as my keyboard and design in file nib.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write this;-

```
*yourtextfieldname*.inputView=*yourcustomkeyboardviewname*;
```

From Apple Docs:-

inputView

The custom input view to display when the text field becomes the first responder.

@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView

Discussion
If the value in this property is nil, the text field displays the standard system keyboard when it becomes first responder. Assigning a custom view to this property causes that view to be presented instead.

The default value of this property is nil.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html